# datepiker para poder seleccionar hora

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un datepiker en el html y me gustaría seleccionar la fecha y hora.

el placeholder lo tengo así:

```
<input placeholder="Fecha a la que quieres iniciar la reunión" id="dateenviar" type="text" class="datepicker">
```

y en el html tengo puesto un script de su configuración

```
       <script >
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format:'yyyy-mm-dd'
      });

      
     });
   </script>
```

el tema es que cuando pulso sobre el placeholder, solo me deja seleccionar la fecha, pero necesito la HORA

he probado a poner en el format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm pero no funciona

Comment: Hola!! probaste con un input type="datetime-local" ?? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Comment: @ebsigma el priemr error es que estas usando un datepicker no un datetimepicker son cosas diferentes el datepicker solamente es para fechas en cambio el datetimepicker tiene la opcion de horas, minutos y segundos.

Comment: agregando al comentario del compañero, al final de tu input, le falta un "slash" de cierre />

Comment: Si quieres la hora, lo que tendrías que indicar es un datetimepicker y no un datepicker. https://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: Gracias, pero no me está funcionando... estoy utilizando materialize, por lo que he puesto dos input finalmente, uno para el dia y otro para la hora.